# Locução Adjetiva para representar "Fogo"

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, sinônimos

Quando se trata de termos elementais, apesar de correto, não fica muito elegante, dependendo do contexto, escrever algo como *de água*, *de terra* e etc.

Então usamos locuções adjetivas para isso: *aquático*, *terrestre*, *aéreo*...

Mas e pra **fogo**?

[Eu pesquisei](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf34.php), bem superficialmente admito, e encontrei **ígneo**. Mas é uma palavra tão pouco utilizada, relativamente falando, que ficaria ainda mais esquisito do que usar **de fogo**:

> O Tocha Humana tem poderes de fogo

Ou:

> O Tocha Humana tem poderes ígneos

Existe algum sinônimo mais... coloquial?

Caso não tenha, ou este possa ser ainda mais difícil de se encaixar num público-alvo que não conheça o *Portuguese Stack Exchange* (sic), seria errado usar as locuções adjetivas para todos os mais "comuns" e manter apenas este mais particular preposicionado?

Comment: Já aprendi uma palavra nova hoje, *elementais*. Alias, duas, *ígneo* também.

Comment: Que tal *ardente*? Pelo menos o que os ingleses chamam *firewater* (literalmente 'água de fogo'), nós chamamos *aguardente*.

Comment: Mas imagina usar, por exemplo, numa história em quadrinhos: `esfera de água` = `esfera aquática` / `esfera de fogo` = `esfera ardente`. Perde a significância da expressão

Comment: Esfera de fogo pode ser pirosfera (mas é não sei se tem registro formal nesse sentido), ou bola de fogo; Poderes de fogo geralmente usam poderes pirocinéticos pois necessitam de algum controle mental para fazerem sentido; Para coisas que pegam fogo usam 'incandescentes', 'em chamas', 'vulcânicos', 'que causam queimaduras', 'flamejantes', 'pirotécnicos', '

Comment: Bruno, tens que incluir @ (@jacinto) para eu ser notificado, a menos que seja num post meu (tal como aqui não é preciso @ no teu nome, porque é na tua pergunta). Sim uma esfera ardente poderia ser uma esfera de madeira ou gás a arder. Imagino que queiras uma esfera de fogo puro. Mas não existe fogo sem combustível! *Esfera aquática*, talvez em contexto soe diferente, mas a mim faz-me lembrar uma esfera na água não uma esfera constituída por água. Tal como desportos aquáticos.

Comment: ao invés de usar ígneos, pode usar - poderes Ignescentes, incandescentes, inflamáveis,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De todas as opções sugeridas nos comentários até agora, *ígneos* é a mais fiel ao significado que você busca, mas entendo que pode não ser compreendida por boa parte do seu público. Se quer ser coloquial, talvez seja melhor dizer assim:

> O Tocha Humana tem **o poder do fogo**

Te garanto que uma criança de 5 anos vai entender exatamente o que você quer dizer.

Answer (score 4):

Creio que com todos os exemplos que você recebeu até agora já tenha solucionado sua dúvida. Dentre todos eles, minha escolha seria "flamejante".

No entanto, me arrisco a citar outra opção que parece bastante adequada, ao menos levando em consideração o seu exemplo, que é "incendiário".

> Enquanto o Aquaman tem poderes aquáticos, o Tocha Humana tem poderes
>   **incendiários**.

Veja o uso [neste texto](http://enquadrinhados.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/curiosidade-hq-16-personagens.html) que encontrei na internet (o destaque é meu):

> Labareda(DC Comics)- Integrante dos Novos Titãs e tem poderes **incendiários**. A DC tem muitos personagens subaproveitados então esperem muitos deles aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, eu diria que você não quer uma locução adjetiva para para representar “Fogo”. Você quer um "*sinônimo*" para não ficar sempre repetindo "de fogo" e acha que "ígneo" é muito formal para quem estiver a ler e provavelmente é.

Com base nessa premissa, creio que quase todas as respostas estão corretas e podem ser usadas, até porque o Tocha humana não tem poderes de fogo já que fogo não dá o poder de voar, por exemplo.

Quando ele se incendeia, ele usa poderes flamejantes ou incandescentes. Quando ele lança rajadas de fogo e queima, ele usa poderes incendiários. Etc...

É importante perceber que, [por definição](http://ucteorias.blogspot.pt/2010/06/axiomas-da-comunicacao.html), "*a comunicação tem um conteúdo e uma relação, sendo esta uma metacomunicação*" ou seja, toda mensagem precisa de um contexto.

Mais importante do que focar no "de fogo" é perceber o que o "de fogo" significa naquele contexto exato, porque os poderes "de fogo" do Tocha humana variam ao longo de uma narrativa e vão tornando-se "de chamas", "de voo", "de luz", "de calor", etc...

E é aqui que está a resposta: perceber o contento exato do "de fogo" naquele momento e usar a locação mais adequada.